# Object does not contain extension Method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Below are the snippets of my code …

Extension:

```
namespace OB{
    public static class OpenXMLExtensions {
        //Add Paragraph
        public static Paragraph AddParagraph(this Body body){
            return body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
            // return body;
        }
        
        //Add Run
        public static Run AddRun(this Body body){
            return body.AddParagraph().AppendChild(new Run());
            // body.AppendChild(new Paragraph()).AppendChild(new Run());
            // return body;
        }
        
        //Add Text
        public static Text AddText(this Body body, string text = ""){
            return body.AddRun().AppendChild(new Text(text));
            // body.AppendChild(new Paragraph((new Run(new Text(text)))));
            // return body;
        }
}}
```

This call works:

```
OB.WordDocument dokument = new OB.WordDocument(outputFilePath, "o");
Body dok_body = dokument.body;
dok_body.AddText('text');
```

This call does not work:

```
public static dynamic ProcessReportDefinition(dynamic parentElement, OB.ReportDefinition.ReportItem reportItem, OB.TenableSC.Json snapshot_data, int level=0){
parentElement.AddText('text');
}
OB.WordDocument dokument = new OB.WordDocument(outputFilePath, "o");
Body dok_body = dokument.body;
**OB.ReportFunctions.ProcessReportDefinition(dokument.body, item, data);**
```

I checked if VSCode recognises the extension inside the `ProcessReportDefinition` method. It does.
Compiler throws:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body' does not contain a definition for 'AddText'

Comment: The compiler should be giving you an error for having `'text'` in single quotes

Answer (score 0):

You are using "dynamic". If you add cast, it will work:

```
((Body)parentElement).AddText('text');
```

Comment: Hi Mykhailo, thank you for quick answer. parentElement can be a number of object types. For each of those I created Extension AddText. This is the reason I am using dynamic.